# beautifulsoup get_text() returns empty string

Tags: python, string, text, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get some text out of a beautifulsoup tag (`<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`) which is as follow:

```
area = <td class="classified-table__data">
         134
         <span class="abbreviation">
             <span aria-hidden="true">
                m²
             </span>
             <span class="sr-only">
                mètres carrés
             </span>
         </span>
       </td>
```

I would like to extract the value "134". Or if not possible I could also extract "134 m²" or "134 mètres carrés".

- When I use `.get_text(separator=" ")` it returns an empty string.
- When I use `.string.strip()` it returns an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`
- When I use `.strings` it returns: `<generator object Tag._all_strings at 0x0000022E30AC8F90>`

I'm a bit lost, not sure what else to do. Where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td class="classified-table__data">
 134
 <span class="abbreviation">
  <span aria-hidden="true">
   m²
  </span>
  <span class="sr-only">
   mètres carrés
  </span>
 </span>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
if soup.find("span"):
    soup.find("span").decompose()


print(soup.text.strip())
```

Output: `134`

Alternatively, if you do not want to remove the text inside the span element:

```py
result = " ".join(soup.text.split())
print(result)
```

Output: `134 m² mètres carrés`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
area = '''
    <td class="classified-table__data">
        134
        <span class="abbreviation">
            <span aria-hidden="true">
                m²
            </span>
            <span class="sr-only">
                mètres carrés
            </span>
        </span>
    </td>'''
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(area, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all('td', {"class": "classified-table__data"})
text = text[0].get_text().strip()
print(text)
'134\n        \n\n                m²\n            \n\n                mètres carrés'

text_split = re.split('\s+', text)
text_split
['134', 'm²', 'mètres', 'carrés']

text_split[0]
'134'

' '.join(text_split[:2])
'134 m²'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find(text=True)` to get first text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <td class="classified-table__data">
         134
         <span class="abbreviation">
             <span aria-hidden="true">
                m²
             </span>
             <span class="sr-only">
                mètres carrés
             </span>
         </span>
    </td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

v = soup.select_one(".classified-table__data").find(text=True)
print(v.strip())
```

Prints:

```
134
```

---

Or: `.contents[0]`

```
v = soup.select_one(".classified-table__data").contents[0]
print(v.strip())
```